# Converting scientific notation to decimal number

Tags: go

I have a number stored as a float64 in scientific notation 6.316159832682479e-06 what is the best way to convert this to a normal decimal number (0.000006316159832682479) and still keep it in the float64. I require the normal decimal for further calculations and for an api call.

```
...
fmt.Printf("%v,%T",ol,ol)
...

Prints: 6.34e-06,float64
```

Comment: hi, i have edited the question. hope it makes it more clear

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/inQBs_SB-pz

Comment: thank so much. I am not looking to print the value i would like to use the value for further calculations

Comment: You can use `Sprintf` to get the value as it would print it with `Printf` and work with it.

Comment: thanks i dont want to print the value, i want to use it in a further calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to decimal number"? Do you mean obtaining a string which actually reads `6.316159832682479e-06`?

Comment: real number is = 0.000006316159832682479

Comment: The problem with your terminology is that "decimal number" means a number _represented_ using base-10 positional numeral system. Both 6.316159832682479e-06 and 0.000006316159832682479 are decimal numbers.

Comment: `6.316159832682479e-06` and `0.000006316159832682479` are different string representations of the same float64 value.   Is your question about how to create different string representations of the value, or is the question about computing a new value in some way?

Comment: cool thanks, what would be the best way to describe the number 0.000006316159832682479. i will edit the question

Comment: Sprintf doesnt print it. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fmt-sprintf-function-in-golang-with-examples/

Comment: Again, both these represent the same flaot64, there is nothing to convert, it is only dependent on how you format them as a string. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i need to pass the real value into an api call

Comment: If you need to do calculations with so much decimal points, and you need exact precision, consider using a decimal package, for example [github.com/shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you do not need to convert the value for any further calculations. Both numbers you provided in your question describe the same float64 value. Any calculation on the number will yield the same result, regardless of its formatting.

As for formatting the string representation of that value, you can use the `strconv.FormatFloat()` function [(docs)](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#FormatFloat) to have full control over how the floating-point number is formatted.

The example will print a decimal representation of the number without any exponents:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    d := 0.000006316159832682479

    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(d, 'f', -1, 64))
}
```

Note also that you can achieve similar results with `fmt.Sprintf()` using other format strings. See the documentation for the `fmt` package [here](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt).